# created element not styling with current JS code

Tags: javascript, styles, createelement

I created an element in JS to be displayed on the html web page. I am not seeing why the styling is not working properly. Maybe someone would be so kind as to point out any error I may have made. Thank you.

```
///HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WEB 115 Final Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <script src= "projectJS.js"></script>

    </body>


</html>
///JS
var elemH1 = document.createElement("h1");
elemH1.style.color = "red";
elemH1.style.fontFamily = "Tahoma";
elemH1.style.textAlign = "center";
document.write("<h1>Kent Butler</h1>");

var elemH2 = document.createElement("h2");
elemH2.style.fontFamily = "Garamond";
elemH2.style.color = "red";
elemH2.style.fontStyle = "italic";
elemH2.style.textAlign = "center";
document.write("<h2>WEB 115.0001</h2>");
```

I am looking for the text to styled red and with the specified font families, etc. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you need to set the text on your elements and then add them to document.body

```
var elemH1 = document.createElement("h1");
elemH1.style.color = "red";
elemH1.style.fontFamily = "Tahoma";
elemH1.style.textAlign = "center";
elemH1.innerText = "Kent Butler";
document.body.appendChild(elemH1);
//document.write("<h1>Kent Butler</h1>");

var elemH2 = document.createElement("h2");
elemH2.style.fontFamily = "Garamond";
elemH2.style.color = "red";
elemH2.style.fontStyle = "italic";
elemH2.style.textAlign = "center";
//document.write("<h2>WEB 115.0001</h2>");
elemH2.innerText = "WEB 115.0001";
document.body.appendChild(elemH2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're creating the element and setting it's properties but you're not actually using them. Instead, you are creating a whole new element without any style attached in `document.write("<h1>Kent Butler</h1>")`

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should consider putting the styling in a CSS file instead of hard coding it with JS.